# How to do a Hermitian matrix decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I want to recover the matrix $A$ out of the Hermitian matrix $H$ such that:

$$H = A\cdot A'$$ where :

- $H$ is a hermitian matrix.
- $A$  is a non-square matrix.
- $A'$ is the conjugate transpose of the matrix $A$ .

Comment: This is only possible if $H$ is positive definite.  That is, in addition to being Hermitian, it must also have non-negative eigenvalues.

Comment: $A$ can only be chosen to be non-square if the rank of $H$ is less than its size.  That is, $A$ can only be chosen to be non-square if $H$ has zero as an eigenvalue.